# Fixed modal footer above scrollable content

Tags: html, css, materialize

I can't seem to get the footer in my modal to be fixed at the bottom with the content scrolling underneath.

```
<div id="children-modal" class="modal" materialize="modal" [materializeParams]="[{dismissible: false}]" [materializeActions]="modalActions">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4 id="modal-title">What to do with your god damn kids</h4>
    <p id="modal-text">A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a id="close-modal-button" class="right waves-effect waves-white btn-flat" (click)="closeModal()">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>

.modal {
  width: 95%;
  padding: 0px;
}

.modal-content {
  height: auto !important;
  padding: 0px;
}

.modal-footer {
  position: fixed;
}
```

The footer disappears. Any ideas?

Comment: delete the .modal-footer class from your CSS entirely. Position:fixed won't work because it means exactly that. It is fixed and once your modal changes its dimension your layout is gone.

Comment: Right ok, I've done this, but now the footer can only be found when i scroll to the bottom of the modal content as opposed to being there all the time and just the modal content scrolling

Comment: set a fixed height property to the modal content and then add overflow-y: scroll property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm building off of sunil's answer. In addition to using bottom: 0, you need to set a height and remove the overflow on your `.modal` class. Next, set the height and overflow to auto on the content like so:

```
.modal {
position: fixed;
left:0;
right:0;
background-color: #fafafa;
max-height:70%;
height: 70%;
margin:auto
border-radius:2px;
will-change:top,opacity;
}

.modal-content[_ngcontent-c0]{
height:90%;
padding:0;
overflow: auto;
}
```

In short, you want it to scroll the content (and not the footer) so this is where you place the height and overflow (scrollbar).

Answer (score 0):

You need to give bottom: 0; to your modal-footer class.

Comment: Thanks for replying, this has made the footer visible, but it is scrolling with the content.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle link for it? I copied the above code and tried running it in jsfiddle. The modal-footer div is sticked to the bottom. https://jsfiddle.net/ozk1f5hu/.
Both position: fixed and bottom: 0 needs to be applied.

Comment: Hmm, when i paste my code in it works in the fiddle, but not on my side, i cant see why. Here's the page https://scottandviki.herokuapp.com/# and the code https://github.com/wrumble/scottandviki Any ideas?